# Seperate Camera and Player Movement in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I'm currently trying to script a camera that has the player in focus and can move around unlinked to the players own movement.
You can control the camera with the right xBox controller.
The camera should move normally on the X axis in an orbit around the player, but if you move the camera to look up or down (let's say 20° up) it should be on 0° to focus the player again if u let off the joystick and interpolate between those two angles.

In my script the camera is able to look up and down (but the degree isn't locked yet so you could move it on the Y axis 360°+) but it resets to 0°. Additionally the x axis doesn't behave as I want it to since it is able to rotate around the player but only 180° and then it stops and if u let the controller go it also sets it's values back (which I don't want for the x axis).

The camera is a child object of an empty game object. The script is attached to the empty game object.

I'm trying to figure this out since ~3 days and I'd be really grateful for any small advice. 
Thanks in advance & here's my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject target;
    public GameObject cameraRig;
    public float rotateSpeedX = 90.0f;
    public float rotateSpeedY = 5f;

    float cameraAngle;

    float startCameraAngle;

    Vector3 offset;
    Vector3 currentOffset;

    public float minRotationY;
    public float maxRotationY;

    bool isCameraMoving;

    void Start()
    {
        offset = transform.position - target.transform.position;

        cameraAngle = transform.localEulerAngles.z;
        startCameraAngle = cameraAngle;
        currentOffset = offset;

    }

    void Update()
    {

        transform.position = target.transform.position + currentOffset; // Folgt dem Spieler

        float hor = Input.GetAxis("RightJoystickX") * rotateSpeedX; // Input rechter Joystick
        float ver = Input.GetAxis("RightJoystickY") * rotateSpeedY;



        if (!Mathf.Approximately (hor, 0)) {
            transform.RotateAround (target.transform.position, Vector3.up, hor);
            currentOffset = transform.position - target.transform.position;

        }   

        if (!Mathf.Approximately (ver, 0)) {

            cameraAngle += 110f * Time.deltaTime;

            transform.RotateAround (target.transform.position, Vector3.up, hor);
            currentOffset = transform.position - target.transform.position;
            print(ver);

        }

        else if (ver <= 0.8f) {
            //cameraAngle = Mathf.Lerp(cameraAngle, startCameraAngle, 1f - 0.1f * Time.deltaTime);
            cameraAngle = startCameraAngle;
        }

        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, hor, cameraAngle);


    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

If sb else googled this and found my question this worked for me:

```
  using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class CameraFollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour
    {

        public GameObject target;
        public GameObject cameraRig;
        public float rotateSpeedX = 9.0f;
        public float rotateSpeedY = 5f;

        float cameraAngle;
        float startCameraAngle;

        Vector3 offset;
        Vector3 currentOffset;

        bool isCameraMoving;


        void Start()
        {
            offset = transform.position - target.transform.position;

            cameraAngle = transform.localEulerAngles.z;
            startCameraAngle = cameraAngle;
            currentOffset = offset;

        }

        void Update()
        {

            transform.position = target.transform.position + currentOffset; // Folgt dem Spieler

            float hor = Input.GetAxisRaw("RightJoystickX") * rotateSpeedX; // Input rechter Joystick    GetAxis wenn Bewegung ausschwingen soll
            float ver = Input.GetAxisRaw("RightJoystickY") * rotateSpeedY; // GetAxis wenn Bewegung ausschwingen soll


            if (!Mathf.Approximately (hor, 0)) {
                transform.RotateAround (target.transform.position, Vector3.up, hor);
                currentOffset = transform.position - target.transform.position;

            }


            if (ver != 0) {

                //cameraAngle += 110f * Time.deltaTime;
                if (ver > 0)
                {

                    cameraAngle += 110f * Time.deltaTime;
                    if (cameraAngle >= 420f)
                    {
                        cameraAngle = 420f;
                    }

                }
                if (ver < 0)
                {

                    cameraAngle -= 110f * Time.deltaTime;

                    if (cameraAngle <= 290f)
                    {
                        cameraAngle = 290f;
                    }
                }


                transform.RotateAround (target.transform.position, Vector3.up, hor);
                currentOffset = transform.position - target.transform.position;
                transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.localEulerAngles.x, transform.localEulerAngles.y, cameraAngle);

            }

            else
            {
                cameraAngle = Mathf.Lerp(startCameraAngle, cameraAngle, 1f - 0.9f * Time.deltaTime);
                transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.localEulerAngles.x, transform.localEulerAngles.y, cameraAngle);

            }
```

Comment: If this has worked for you, you can accept your own answer also.(After 48 hour) . If you wish to read about it please check [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)